# loading function not working with isonscreen function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a progress bar on my website. I want to animate the progress bar only when it is visible on the screen. But this code is not working:

```
$(document).scroll(function(event){
    var result = $('#skil').isOnScreen();
    if(result)
    {
        $(".progress-bar1").loading();
    }
});
```

When using `$(".progress-bar1").loading();` without jquery function it is loading when the screen loads. But I want it to load only when the section is visible.. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You probably make your section visible when load data via ajax, then do show your progress bar when ajax starts load and hide it when load complete.

Otherwise if  you share mode code I could provide more specific answer with code.

Good luck

Comment: But I don't know anything on ajax

Comment: Share your relevant code about `$(".progress-bar1").loading();` where you "screen loads"